# How to display / delete the image after saving in the gallery?

Tags: flutter, dart

After saving the image in gallery using *image_gallery_saver* and *permission_handler*
This is the result

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/TestImage.jpg
```

my questions :

- How to display the image in a container?
- How to delete it ?

Note: I used image_picker in my app But I want to display the image after saving it automatically,

save image code is

```
 Future<String> saveImage (Uint8List bytes) async {
    await [Permission.storage].request();
    final name = 'TestImage';
    final result = await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(bytes,name:name);
    print(result ["filePath"]);
    return result ["filePath"];
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the user to pick it from gallery, you can use [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) but if you want to open it yourself from the path use:

```
Image.file(File(path))
```

Also for deleting you can use:

```
img = File(path)

Future<int> deleteFile() async {
        try {
          await img.delete();
        } catch (e) {
          return 0;
        }
      }
```